# WPF binding objects to Listbox, text not appearing

Tags: wpf, binding

I searched and could not find an answer to my problem can someone help? I tried to bind a list of objects to a listbox. I have the correct number of items (I can still select them) but I could not see the texts.

My Xaml Code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox_leave" BorderThickness="0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding leaveName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding numberOfDays}" />
            </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is backend code:

```
ObservableCollection<Leave> leavelist = new ObservableCollection<Leave>(); 
leavelist = DbControl.loadLeaveDetails();
listbox_leave.ItemsSource = leavelist;
```

and my Leave Class:

```
class Leave
{
    public string leaveName;

    public string LeaveName
    {
        get { return leaveName; }
        set { leaveName = value; }
    }

    public string numberOfDays;

    public string NumberOfDays
    {
        get { return numberOfDays; }
        set { numberOfDays = value; }
    }
}
```

When I debug, the `ObservableCollection` list of Leave has all the correct data, my listbox display blank but it have the correct number of object Leave in it (I could select them) but there is no text displaying. And I have this msg:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'leaveName' property not found on 'object' ''Leave' (HashCode=44930696)'. BindingExpression:Path=leaveName; DataItem='Leave' (HashCode=44930696); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'numberOfDays' property not found on 'object' ''Leave' (HashCode=44930696)'. BindingExpression:Path=numberOfDays; DataItem='Leave' (HashCode=44930696); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'leaveName' property not found on 'object' ''Leave' (HashCode=29274103)'. BindingExpression:Path=leaveName; DataItem='Leave' (HashCode=29274103); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'numberOfDays' property not found on 'object' ''Leave' (HashCode=29274103)'. BindingExpression:Path=numberOfDays; DataItem='Leave' (HashCode=29274103); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Can Someone help??

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind to the fields (`leaveName` and `numberOfDays`) instead of the properties (`LeaveName` and `NumberOfDays`), and this is not supported in WPF.

Change it to:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox_leave" BorderThickness="0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding LeaveName}" />
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumberOfDays}" />
          </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Also, you should probably go ahead and make the fields `private` (`leaveName` and `numberOfDays`) instead of `public`.